# What is "field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:" in k8s service annotation?

Tags: kubernetes, service, rancher, cattle

I am maintaining an on-premise k8s cluster.
There is a service that has an annotation "field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:"

I tried to figure it out and got a clue that it is related to 'Rancher'. (this is the clue https://github.com/rancher/rancher/blob/a9ea4ce4a5bab9dd112cd20c9e250aba4dbe5176/pkg/controllers/managementagent/endpoints/endpoints.go#L30)

However, there is no documentation or description about this annotation.
I think it's quite old.

I wonder if this annotation has a role in fixing public external-ip like 'loadBalancerIP' in kubernetes service.

I think it's may not. But this service is very important service. So I have to figure it out. please somebody help me.